# How do you find the most common edge in a graph?

Tags: python

The problem is that there are N cities connected by M roads. There can only be one road between two cities and one city can only have 10 other cities connected to it at maximum.The aim is to find a road which is common in as many paths(road or combination of roads). How do you go about doing this?
Ex:

```
Cities = [1,2,3,4,5] #Assume that the cities are numbered from 1 to N
Roads = [(5,4), (4,3), (3,2), (2,1)]
```

The output should be (2,3) as it is common to the paths (5,1), (5,2), (4,1), (4,2), (3,1), (3,2)

Comment: Can you post the code you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the edges in a graph by -

```
# Returns count of edge in undirected graph  
    def countEdges(self): 
        Sum = 0
      
        # traverse all vertex  
        for i in range(self.V): 
      
            # add all edge that are linked  
            # to the current vertex  
            Sum += len(self.adj[i])  
      
        # The count of edge is always even   
        # because in undirected graph every edge   
        # is connected twice between two vertices  
        return Sum // 2
```

then you can traverse the list of adj edges and find the maximum value of adjacent sides to an edge to find the most common edge of the graph.